# Excel VBA CommandBars

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel-model used for extracting data via S&P Capital IQ Excel-plugin (COM-Addin). This model has been used for a few years without any issues, but now I am getting an error on this line of code:

```
    Application.CommandBars.FindControl(Tag:="menurefreshdatacell").Execute
```

I have tried searching around and have found that the CommandBars may have been replaced by the Microsoft Office Fluent user interface. However, I cannot seem to find a solution or example of how this may have changed the piece of code from above.

Been a while since i've been using VBA, so unfortunately I have not been able to solve the issue myself, hope to find some more competent people in here.

Below is the entire piece of code. Which selects a designated area, and presses an "Refresh Selection"-button in the plugin.

Let me know if I have left out anything, thank you very much in advance!

```
    Sub Update_FactSet_formulas()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Peer group_segments").Select
    Range("PG_seg_data").Select

    Application.CommandBars.FindControl(Tag:="menurefreshdatacell").Execute
```

Below is the fomula that is provided by the plugin author, this has not changed for years, and what the above should reflect:

```
    Public Sub RefreshSelection()
    Dim Refreshbutton As CommandBarButton
    Set Refreshbutton = 
    Application.CommandBars.FindControl(Tag:="menurefreshdatacell")
    Refreshbutton.Execute
End Sub
```

Comment: Just guessing, but you might have success by replacing the code line in question by ``ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll``.

Comment: If you UDF is in a module, can't you just call the UDF rather than trying to interact with commandbar?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following worked for me:

`Application.Run("CIQKEYS_RefreshSelection")`

The function comes from the ciqfunctions library, but you don't have to add the reference for it to work. However, you can add the library by doing the following:

1. Tools
2. References
3. Check ciqfunctions
4. click OK

To see all of the functions available in the library:

1. Go to View
2. Select Object Brow
3. Check ciqfunctions
4. from the dropdown menu in the top left corner that likely says "", select ciqfunctions
5. Under Classes, select IUdf
6. The functions should appear in the "Members" column

Again, note that for the code to work for me, I didn't need to have the library added to references, I just wanted to outline how to explore the library, should you choose to.

There are also the following refresh functions:

```
CIQKEYS_RefreshWorkBook
CIQKEYS_RefreshWorkBookRangeV
CIQKEYS_RefreshWorkSheet
CIQKEYS_RefreshWorkSheetRangeV
```

Hope this works for you!